# Convert HTTP Request headers into CURL Request

Tags: php, curl, http-post, forms

I have HTTP Request Headers as given below is it possible to convert them to curl request.How can I achieve it?

```
POST http://something.org.in/cool HTTP/1.1
Host: something.org.in
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://something.org.in
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://something.org.in/nice
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AKFD08Azc-yU5nP3VRsPJXerwM4dj4yec.N6Ko3n9vWY15ghJzxZz7FyvZme9ERWANEFc%2Brz0mthU
```

Comment: I believe that this page can help you https://curl.haxx.se/h2c/

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure that I understand the question correctly, but since it is tagged as PHP questions I assume you want to perform the same or a similar request in PHP with curl.

In PHP, you can use the function [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with the argument `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to specifiy the headers of an HTTP request. In that case, the third argument of the function must be an array that contains the (=all) headers.

Basic code could be as follows:

```
<?php
// initialize curl handle
$ch = curl_init();
// set request URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://something.org.in/cool');
// We don't want to get the headers in the response, but just the content.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// It's a POST method request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// set cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'connect.sid=s0X0P+0KFD08Azc-yU5nP3');

// Now set the HTTP request headers.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8'
    // ... and add more, if needed
));

// execute the request
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Any error handling is omitted to keep it simple.

A similar request with `curl` from the command line could be created like this: (I am omitting some of the headers to keep the example shorter.)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml' \
   -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' \
   --cookie "connect.sid=s0X0P+0KFD08Azc-yU5nP3"
   -i 'http://something.org.in/cool'
```

With `-X POST` you can enforce the POST method for the request, and with `-H 'Header: value'` you can add a header and its value. This can be repeated multiple times, if more than one header is required. The `--cookie` option obviously sets the cookies. Setting multiple cookies requires them to be separated by `;`, e.g. as in `--cookie "first=value;second=another"`.